# Devise: require admin to activate user before sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Please can someone help me try to understand this component of the instructions on the devise wiki for requiring the admin to activate an account before sign in. 
[https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in)

What do the words 'new_user_waiting_for_approval' do? What do they need to function? I don't have a method defined as that anywhere and I don't have an attribute in my user model called that.  I'm getting a syntax error when I follow that wiki. It's identifying that statement as having a syntax error. I wonder if the problem is that those words aren't defined anywhere is actually the problem. Thank you very much.

```
after_create :send_admin_mail
  def send_admin_mail
    AdminMailer.new_user_waiting_for_approval(self).deliver
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new_user_waiting_for_approval` is a Mailer function. Create a mailer(follow [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) or [this](http://www.intelligentbee.com/blog/2013/09/27/create-a-mailer-in-rails-4/)) with a function called `new_user_waiting_for_approval`. They are sending a mail after the user is created. You can do it inside the controller as well if you are confused. Totally up to you.

Comment: Thank you Aravind. I created a mailer called 'send_admin_mail'. I'll try it now. Thank you & fingers crossed.

Comment: @user2860931 what happened?

Comment: Hey Aravind. After a bit of fiddling, I got the registration form to complete without an error, so thanks for your help with the setup. It doesn't actually send me an email though. I have some more digging to do to get it working. Thanks very much for your help though.